# how to get parameters from command line in unix script

Tags: unix, command-line-arguments

I have to write script in unix.

When I call it like:

```
./check -l word1 -c word2,
```

I need to fetch the word which is used with commands -l and -c from inside script.

Comment: @Blender I'm assuming bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getopts` as shown in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts l:c: option
do
    case "$option" in
        l) 
           loption="$OPTARG"
           ;;
        c)
           coption="$OPTARG"
           ;;
    esac
done

echo "L is: $loption"
echo "C is: $coption"
```